# foreach HTML table

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando novamente criar uma tabela com os dados inseridos usando

```
$_SESSION

    <?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Lista de contatos</legend>
            <label for="name">
                Nome:
                <input type="text" name="nome" id="name">
            </label><br>
            <label for="tel">
                telefone:
                <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel">
            </label><br>
            <label for="email">
                E-mail:
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <?php 
           $contatos = [];

            if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)) {
                $_SESSION[contatos]['nome'][] = $_GET['nome'];
             }
            if (array_key_exists('tel', $_GET)) {
                $_SESSION[contatos]['tel'][] = $_GET['tel'];
            }
            if (array_key_exists('email',$_GET)) {
                $_SESSION[contatos]['email'][] = $_GET['email'];
            }
            $contatos = [];
            if (array_key_exists('contatos',$_SESSION)) {
                $contatos = $_SESSION['contatos'];
            }
    ?>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>telefone</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($contatos as $contato=>$value) : ?>

        </tr> 
            <?php for($i=0; $i < count($value); $i++): ?>

                    <td><?php echo $value[$i]; ?></td>

            <?php endfor; ?>
        </tr>              

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

está armazenando normal, porém não está seguindo a ordem da tabela.
[image: tabela]

Comment: Vide mensagem, em `$_SESSION[contatos]` o `contatos` não está definido. Se é para ser uma variável, faltou o $ na frente, mas faz sentido ter um array vazio como chave da sessão? Se era para ser string faltaram as aspas

Comment: Retirei o contatos vazio, mas mesmo assim não está seguindo a ordem da tabela; Esta ficando tudo numa só coluna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
session_start();
//unset($_SESSION['contatos']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Lista de contatos</legend>
        <label for="name">
            Nome:
            <input type="text" name="nome" id="name">
        </label><br>
        <label for="tel">
            telefone:
            <input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel">
        </label><br>
        <label for="email">
            E-mail:
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
    </fieldset>
</form>

 <?php 
        $contatos = [];

        if (array_key_exists('nome', $_GET)) {
            $_SESSION['contatos']['nome'][] = $_GET['nome'];
         }
        if (array_key_exists('tel', $_GET)) {
            $_SESSION['contatos']['tel'][] = $_GET['tel'];
        }
        if (array_key_exists('email',$_GET)) {
            $_SESSION['contatos']['email'][] = $_GET['email'];
        }

        if (array_key_exists('contatos',$_SESSION)) {
            $contatos = $_SESSION['contatos'];
        }
?>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>telefone</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
    </tr>
    <?php for($i=0; $i < count($contatos['nome']); $i++): ?>
        <tr> 
            <td><?php echo $contatos['nome'][$i];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contatos['tel'][$i];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contatos['email'][$i];?></td>
        </tr>    
    <?php endfor;?>
</table>
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, continua na mesma coluna.
Tentei deixar a <tr> fora do laço e também não funcionou, continuo pesquisando.
Desde já, agradeço o tempo dispensado.

Comment: @Carlos1br tenta agora, refiz o codigo

Comment: Agora funcionou, e entendi a lógica! Muito Obrigado!